# Is std::list order guaranteed?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Is the order of the elements within an `std::list` guaranteed to remain in-order (unless, of course, a sort or something occurs)?

Moreover, is there any potentially undefined behavior with lists that might jumble them up?

I was/am under the impression that containers such as `std::deque` and the like are order-safe, but alas `std::deque` is not double-linked.

Comment: What makes you suppose that the std::list implementation of a linked list is NOT preserving its order?

Comment: @DavidO - Nothing; it was just a thought. I figured they were, but more often than not there is something hidden that others know that I don't.

Comment: Well, like `std::vector` and `std::deque` (and any good old array) it's a sequence container. It would loose its sense pretty much if the library could reorder its elements at random.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the order is guaranteed in [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). Since anything can happen with UB, mixing up the order of a std::list is possible (though unlikely I would think).

Short answer is that if your lists are not in the order you think they should be then the most likely reason is a bug in your program.

Comment: It's just about the *only* reason.

Comment: Cool, I figured as much. Just wanted to confirm; I couldn't find anything on the internet warning about it, but that doesn't mean it couldn't happen.

Comment: Perhaps I should have bug in your *logic* rather than a bug in general.